# Upgrade MAMP's Apache Server to 2.4

Tags: apache, upgrade, mamp

I'm currently using MAMP PRO which comes shipped with Apache 2.2 and I have some experience in upgrading/configuring PHP under MAMP in order to install specific modules etc but what I would like to do now is upgrading the Apache HTTP server in order to use a server module that only work in version 2.4, does anyone have experience in doing this?

Comment: I need to do this too now...together with upgrading openssl to 1.0.2...have you succeeded in doing this?

Comment: If you're still in need I'd recommend you to use AMPPS which instead runs apache 2.4.x

Comment: Have a look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206901/147986